# Is there a cleaner way to represent this idiom in C#?

Tags: c#, coding-style, value-type

I am using a struct in a project, like so:

```
struct Position
{
    public int X { get; private set; }
    public int Y { get; private set; }
    // etc
}
```

I would like to add a method that allows me to create a modified copy of the struct with arbitrarily changed properties. For example, it would be convenient to use this:

```
var position = new Position(5, 7);
var newPos = position.With(X: position.X + 1);
```

Is this idiom hacky? Are there better ways to support this?

```
public Position With(int? X = null, int? Y = null)
{
    return new Position(X ?? this.X, Y ?? this.Y);
}
```

Edit: in case it was unclear, the struct is immutable, I simply want to create a new value with some values modified. Incidentally, this is very similar to Haskell's syntactic sugar for records, where one would write `newPos = oldPos { x = x oldPos + 1 }`. This is just a bit experimental as to whether such an idiom is helpful in C#.

Comment: belongs to http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: I would have thought it would be more appropriate to create an interface for a deep clone. Note that using the standard ICloneable is not recommended, see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brada/archive/2003/04/09/49935.aspx

Comment: Do you really need the struct to be mutable at all? And do you definitely need *one* With method instead of two?

Comment: Take a look at DateTime...

Comment: As @AK_ says, have a look at `DateTime` and see if the Add-behaviour is something along the lines of what you need. If not, have a look at `propertyexpression` and see if that looks better to you (the syntax in your example would be `var newPos = orgPos.With(pos => pos.X, orgPos.X + 1);` where it's possible to chain multiple `With` for every property you want to change.). And I'd also recommend to follow @JonSkeet advice on mutability, it doesn't really seem to be needed (in general mutable value-types are a bad idea).

Comment: @JonSkeet I think his struct is Immutable...

Comment: @AK_: Ah, I hadn't spotted that the setter was private. I would personally use a readonly variable and just a getter to be clearer that no methods within the struct could change the value (other than by reassigning `this`, which is always a disturbing possibility.)

Comment: @AK_ Externally yes, internally no. AFAIK an immutable instance is something who's observable state cannot be altered from where-ever, in this case it is actually possible to do that internally (well, since there is reflection in C# I guess immutability doesn't really exist though :) ).

Comment: @JonSkeet the type itself is immutable, I am simply looking for a more convenient way of creating a new instance similar to an existing instance. What I want is equivalent to `var newPos = new Position(orgPos.X + 1, orgPos.Y)`, but I was trying to model this in a somewhat more fluent manner.

Comment: @flindeberg: That's assuming there are no methods that we can't see. Given that in order to be useful there must at least be a *constructor* we can't see, it's not clear that there aren't mutating methods. Again, that's why I'd make it a read-only field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally, I consider the idiom of a plain-old-data-struct to be vastly underrated.  Mutable structs which encapsulate state in anything other than public fields are problematic, but sometimes it's useful to bind together a fixed collection of variables stuck together with duct tape so they can be passed around as a unit.  A plain-old-data-struct is a perfect fit for that usage; it behaves like a fixed collection of variables stuck together with duct tape, since that's what it *is*.  One can with some work come up with an immutable class which requires slow and hard-to-read code to do anything with, or with some more work come up with something that's still slow but not quite so unaesthetic; one can also code structures in such fashion as to mimic such classes.  In many cases, however, the only effect of going through all that effort is that one's code will be slower and less clear than it would have been if one had simply used a PODS.

The key thing that needs to be understood is that a PODS like `struct PersonInfo { public string Name, SSN; public Date Birthdate; }` does *not* represent a person.  It represents a space that can hold two strings and a date.  If one says `var fredSmithInfo = myDatabase.GetPersonInfo("Fred Smith");`, then `FredSmithInfo.BirthDate` doesn't represent Fred Smith's birthdate; it represents a variable of type `Date` which is initially loaded with the value returned by a call to `GetPersonInfo`--but like any other variable of type `Date`, could be changed to hold any other date.

Answer (score 1):

That's about as neat a way as you're going to get. Doesn't seem particularly hacky to me.

Although in cases where you're just doing `position.X + 1` it'd be neater to have something that was like:

```
var position = new Position(5,7);
var newPos = position.Add(new Position(1,0));
```

Which would give you a modified X value but not a modified Y value.

Comment: Seems redundant - they might as well do `position = new Position(...)` in this case.

Comment: It's a consistency thing to just keep it in line with how .Net does things. Think of `DateTime` for instance.

Comment: Adding one *position* to another doesn't make much sense. Yes, you can get it to work in terms of the raw numbers, but it doesn't make *logical* sense. Adding a vector to a position makes much more sense. So while "London + New York" doesn't logically give you a position, "London + 10 miles East" does.

Comment: @JonSkeet I don't disagree - I was specifically referring to OP's example of `position.With(X: position.X + 1);` when I had that in mind.

Answer (score 0):

One could consider this approach as a variant of the [prototype pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prototype_pattern) where the focus is on having a template struct rather than avoiding the cost of new instances. Whether the design is good or bad depends on your context. If you can make the message behind the syntax clear (I think the name `With` you're using is a bit unspecific; maybe something like `CreateVariant` or `CreateMutant` would make the intention clearer), I would consider it an appropriate approach.

Answer (score 0):

I'm adding an expression based form as well. Do note the horrendous boxing/unboxing which needs to be done due to the fact that it is a struct.

But as one can see the format is quite nice:

```
var p2 = p.With(t => t.X, 4);
var p3 = p.With(t => t.Y, 7).With(t => t.X, 5); // Yeah, replace all the values :)
```

And the method is really applicable to all kinds of types.

```
public void Test()
{
  var p = new Position(8, 3);

  var p2 = p.With(t => t.X, 4);
  var p3 = p.With(t => t.Y, 7).With(t => t.X, 5);

  Console.WriteLine(p);
  Console.WriteLine(p2);
  Console.WriteLine(p3);
}

public struct Position
{
  public Position(int X, int Y)
  {
    this._X = X; this._Y = Y;
  }

  private int _X; private int _Y;
  public int X { get { return _X; } private set { _X = value; } }
  public int Y { get { return _Y; } private set { _Y = value; } }

  public Position With<T, P>(Expression<Func<Position, P>> propertyExpression, T value)
  {
    // Copy this
    var copy = (Position)this.MemberwiseClone();
    // Get the expression, might be both MemberExpression and UnaryExpression
    var memExpr = propertyExpression.Body as MemberExpression ?? ((UnaryExpression)propertyExpression.Body).Operand as MemberExpression;
    if (memExpr == null)
      throw new Exception("Empty expression!");

    // Get the propertyinfo, we need this one to set the value
    var propInfo = memExpr.Member as PropertyInfo;
    if (propInfo == null)
      throw new Exception("Not a valid expression!");

    // Set the value via boxing and unboxing (mutable structs are evil :) )
    object copyObj = copy;
    propInfo.SetValue(copyObj, value); // Since struct are passed by value we must box it
    copy = (Position)copyObj;
    // Return the copy
    return copy;
  }

  public override string ToString()
  {
    return string.Format("X:{0,4} Y:{1,4}", this.X, this.Y);
  }
}
```